# Conversion of code from a HashMap to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm new to java and would like to know how I could convert the following code from using a `HashMap` called `floorsMap` to using an `ArrayList` called `floorsArray` instead.

```
void randomizeQueues(String flag) {
    double num = (flag.equals("enforce")) ? 0.99 : Math.random();
    if (num > 0.5)
        floorsMap.values().forEach(Floor::randomizeDestinations);
}
```

Comment: you mean like `floorsArray.forEach(Floor::randomizeDestinations);` ?

Answer (score 4):

`forEach` is a terminal operation; it returns nothing; calling a method that has no side effects is therefore a do-nothing operation.

I think you're looking for a series of operations that convert and then roll the results into a new collection type. The stream API is used to do this:

```java
List<Floor> randomizedFloors = floorsMap.values().stream()
    .map(Floor::randomizeDestinations)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT:

Perhaps `randomizeDestinations` randomizes 'in place' and returns void. In that case you can't keep the map intact and then have a list with randomized destinations unless you have a way to clone the Floor object, which you'd have to explicitly make. You could do:

```java
List<Floor> randomizedFloors = floorsMap.values().stream().map(floor -> {
    Floor clone = floor.makeACopy(); // you must write this
    clone.randomizeDestinations();
    return clone;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I was thinking, would `randomizeDestinations()`  return a Floor object ?

Comment: Anyways..The question needs more clarity !